# eCognition export samples as a shapefile problem

Tags: export, image-segmentation, ecognition, sample

I need sample shapefile for the other project but when I try to export it, it gives me an error like `domain is empty(no images object available)`. How can I get the samples as shapefile?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you only trying to export certain selected features, or all the polygons? In the bottom right of your image it looks like you are exporting selected features - maybe no features have been selected and that's why the domain is empty?

Comment: I am trying to export all the polygons, and also I tried only one selected polygon to export but i got still same error message.